# How do I access classes object from a function outside a stateless component but in the same file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styling

I currently have a function-component (stateless). In that component, I have several render functions that are called inside that component. Although the component itself has access to `classes` object through its props, I need styles in that object inside the render functions that are declared outside.

Here's the structure of my stateless component

```
// MyComponent.js
import React from "react";
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import myStyles from "../mystyles.js"

function MyComponent(props) {
    const { classes } = props;
    return <div className={classes.someClass}>
       ...
    </div>
}
export withStyles(myStyles)(MyComponent)
```

How do I use my `classes` inside another render function present in the same file?

```
// MyComponent.js
const renderSomething = () => {
   // This is not working
   return <div className={myStyles.someClass}></div>
}
```

FYI: I do not want to pass `classes` into that `renderSomething` function in the main component. I want to be able to utilize the classes without passing it, since we are already importing `myStyles`.

Edit 1: I tried applying the class as a style attribute, but that still doesn't apply media queries

Comment: What is the error you're getting? is myStyles undefined? is someClass undefined?

Comment: The style simply doesn't get applied.

Comment: where is `renderSomething` defined exactly? why doesn't it have access to props

Comment: It is defined in the same file

Comment: why doesn't it have access to props? is it just a free floating function? why not make it a component and pass props? that would be the most sensible thing to do